# Time delay neural network in seconds?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, neural-network, matlab-figure, mat

Refering to the link at [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/timedelaynet.html), about the `timedelaynet(inputDelays,hiddenSizes,trainFcn)`, what is the unit for `inputDelays`? Is in in seconds?

Comment: I think it depends on the input data.

Answer (score 0):

The unit is cardinal, i.e. unitless. MATLAB doesn't understand units, it only understands numbers. Thus, whatever units your data have, will be what `inputDelays` will be. If your data is in seconds, so will `inputDelays` be, if your data is in years, so will `inputDelays` be, etc..